# Optimise server for Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j

We're using the latest Neo4J from the 1.9 branch.

I understand how to set the default values for the low-level graph engine by setting the appropriate values in `neo4j.properties` based on the file sizes in the data directory.

What I don't understand though is how to work out how to work out how much memory my graph is using, how to properly allocate the java heap and how that all relates to how much RAM my server needs.

Please could someone explain how to calculate this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the configuration depends on how many nodes and relationships has your graph. If you're using the java core API, you can refer to this page in order to take  a better idea on how to improve the performance of your server http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/embedded-configuration.html. The key is to configure this parameters properly. Also remember that the file sizes is not necessary the size of the graph in memory.